# Random picking of element from each column to make a subset of a data.table

Tags: r

my_data:

```
LCE1B   KIR2DL4 CDC20   CC2D1B  STXBP3  LMLN    SDAD1   NPAS4
NDUFC2  KIR3DL3 IKZF2   CCT6A   TGFBR2  MMP24   PADI4   SCUBE2
SNRPD1  KRT33B  INA     CORO2A  CDKL3   SRPK1   RNF145  SLC45A4
SSNA1   MBTD1   MATN1   FAAH2           SLC9A4  TBL3
TANK            NOS1AP                  SPON1
TMEM14C
```

Desired OUTPUT:

```
NDUFC2  KRT33B  CDC20   CORO2A  TGFBR2  SRPK1   SDAD1  SCUBE2
TMEM14C KRT33B  INA     CC2D1B  STXBP3  SPON1   PADI4  NPAS4
```

I tried using sample

```
sample(1:ncol(my_data), 2, replace=FALSE)
```

It's randomly selecting the row. I need to pick randomly from each column.

Comment: what class has `my_data` ?

Comment: class of 8 columns in a data.table

Comment: `as.data.table(lapply(my_data, sample, 2))`

Answer (score 0):

```
# create the MWE
my_data <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c("", letters[1:24]), 48, replace = TRUE), 6, 8))

apply(my_data, 2, function(col){
    # get non empty values
    cc <- col[col!=""]
    cc[sample(seq(cc), 2, replace=FALSE)]
})
```

Comment: It's not giving my desired output. some of the columns are empty in that 2 rows.

Comment: I edited the answer. Note also that you didn't provide any MWE nor exact expected output